# MVC 5 AJAX Code is not accessing Controller Class Action Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

***The intention of the code:***
The intention of this code is to accept data passed to it through the scope and place in an array to be passed to a Login controller (Server Side) via AJAX.

***The Problem***
The AJAX code does not seem as if it is successfully contacting the serverside action.

1. I have tried moving the action from the login controller to the home controller: ***No success.***
2. I have tried following the guidelines of those who previously ran into this issue: ***No success.***
3. I have tried hardcoding the URL to the action: ***No success.***

Below is the AJAX Call:

```
    login: function (username, password) {
                var cred = { "uname": username, "pass": password };
                var response = $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '@(Url.Action("CheckUser","Login"))',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ model: cred }),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg) {
                            console.log("success: " + msg);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        if (msg) {
                            console.log("Error:" + msg);
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {
                        if (msg) {
                            console.log("fail: " + msg);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Next the action code:

```
     namespace test4.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public class UserCred
        {
            public string Uname { get; set; }
            public string Pass { get; set; }  
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CheckUser(UserCred umodel) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am here");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Content("0");
            }

            string uname = umodel.Uname;
            string pword = umodel.Pass;

            using (localtestEntities entity = new localtestEntities()) {
                var user = entity.users.Where(u => u.uname == uname).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null) {
                    if (pword == user.pw) {
                        Session["LoginID"] = user.id;
                        Session["Username"] = user.fname + ' ' + user.lname;
                        return Content(user.id.ToString());
                    } else {
                        return Content("0");
                    }
                } else {
                    return Content("0");
                }
            }
            /* Begin Assigning values */
        } //End Check User
    }
}
```

The intended result is to pass back to the client side code whether the comparison of strings passed and what is in the database matches.

Comment: Where is that JS executing? Did you check your browser's development console? What error does it say? What URL is being generated? These are all basic things you have to check and include in your post

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This JS code is being executed from my /Scripts/drivers folder, while the controller file is located in /Controllers/LoginControllers. When following the debugger in VS 2017, the code literally dies at "var response...." I tried adding breakpoint in the Action but the code did not get that far.

Comment: So the answer by @keyle56 is actually correct. It was a long shot because it could have been a completely different problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1. `$Http({...` is not an actual ajax function. I would recommend using `$.post()` for `[HttpPost]` and `$.get()` for `[HttpGet]`. You can review this in detail from jQuery's documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
2. That URL will not work. You can't access razor helper methods inside of JS. As is, you're literally passing `@(Url.Action("CheckUser","Login"))` into your url so it would look something like `localhost:3000/@(Url.Action("CheckUser","Login"))` which obviously is not a legit route. You're going to have to get that URL to your ajax function a different way. Some options:

1) In the header of your `.cshtml` file, do something like:

```
    <script>
        $(() => {
            const url = `@Url.Action("CheckUser","Login")`;

            //Pass that into your JS code via a constructor parameter if your JS 
            //is a class or by function parameter if your JS code is a function.
            const myJSClassNameHere = new myJSClassHere(url);
        });
    </script>
```

2) you can just hard code the url into the ajax call. This is a viable option if you don't anticipate the url to change and/or if your standards allow it.

Comment: You are assuming the code was placed in a JS file, but the OP did not say that.

Comment: @keyle56 I tried hardcoding the URL in prior and that did not work.

Comment: @Paradigm can you tell me what the url you hardcoded was?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you're corect, I did assume that but to my knowledge, I don't know where else you could use ajax at?

Comment: In a .cshtml file, you can use a `<script>` tag and add JavaScript like in any HTML file

Comment: @keyle56 the URL was /Login/CheckUser

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If that's the case, my answer is still valid. Inside of the .cshmtl file you can still acess the `@Url.Action...`. That was the main point, OP was trying to access a function that was not available where they were calling it.

Comment: @Paradigm I think I see the problem now. in the ajax call you have this: `data: JSON.stringify({ model: cred }),` when in reality you need a JSON object of the model the controller is expecting. you still need to fix how you are asigning the url but also the model you post back. if the model does not match up to what the controller expects, you will get no luck, I'm going to edit my original answer to include this so check that out momentarily.

Comment: @keyle56 Since I am passing two strings to the Action and it is receiving a model with two strings, wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: MVC tries to "Map" the object you pass it to the object you define in the controller action parameter. right now, you are passing it an object with one property called `model` which on your `UserCred` object, obviously wouldn't map correctly. Check my edit to my OP

Comment: You might even be able to get away with changing your data part of ajax call to: `data: JSON.stringify({ umodel: cred }),` all I did was change the name of the model to match that of what you have called it in your controller action. This may work too.

Comment: @Paradigm I just noticed this too, I've never seen a jQuery ajax call start off with `$http({..` and after googling around for an example using it, it seems that it doesn't exist. I would reccommend using `$.post(url, model, functionToRunOnReturn);` Here is the link to the jQuery documentation regarding this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @keyle56 success!!

Comment: @Paradigm woohoo!!! took a little debugging but we got there haha I'll edit my OP to show this as the solution then.